# How to pass a dict of queryset results to $.json?

Tags: jquery, json, django, django-queryset

Currently I have the following queryset filters:

```
def grab_city_landmark(request):
    State = State.objects.filter(state=state_name)
    City = list(State.valued_list('city', flat=True).distinct())
    Landmark = list(State.valued_list('landmark', flat=True).distinct())

    response = {
         'state': State,
         'city': City,
         'landmark': Landmark,
     }
     return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/javascript")
```

The JQuery call is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON('grab_city_landmark/', {state_name: state}, function(data) {

      ... GRAB DATA HERE ...

      iterate over i
      data['city'][i]
```

My questions are:

1. How do I make the response in json form? Is it in json form?  How do I check? I can't see the object return to jquery. json.dumps(response) doesn't seem to work.
2. How do you take a look in java console what is returned to the jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

response  = json.dumps(list(State),City,Landmark)
return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/javascript")
```

or use the `jsonresponse` of django

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
response = JsonResponse({'state': list(State),'city': City,'landmark': Landmark,})
```

Comment: `State` is queryset

Comment: make it a list then, by putting a list infront of it

Comment: haha, i am sorry bro, i thought you were the OP as you commented :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [Django serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) or [DRF serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), second way may help you create rest api. For example:

```
from django.core import serializers

state = State.objects.filter(state=state_name)
state_data = serializers.serialize("json", state)
city_data = serializers.serialize(
            "json",
            state.distinct('city').order_by(), fields=('city')
            )
```